# Run JMeter test on AWS ec2 instance (ubuntu)

Tags: java, ssl, jmeter, activemq-artemis

I am trying to set up JMeter tests in AWS on an EC2 (t2.micro) instance to run them on cmd.
Therefore I wanted to use this git project: https://github.com/r4dx/terraform-aws-jmeter.

As I am new to terraform and have just basic knowledge of aws, I went step by step. So for first attempts I let the autoscaling group away and want to reach, that I can run one test against another ec2 instance, where there is the artemis broker and some applications running as a cluster.

The ec2 instance is running and has JMeter 3.3 installed. So far I added the test itself as well as the truststore.jks to /bin and a driver for artemis to the /lib folder (artemis-jms-client-all-2.15.0.jar).

When I execute "jmeter -n -t Artemis_AWS.jmx -j jmeterlogfile" I am getting following error:

```
WARNING: An illegal reflective access operation has occurred 
WARNING: Illegal reflective access by com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.util.Fields file:/usr/share/java/xstream.jar) to field java.util.TreeMap.comparator 
WARNING: Please consider reporting this to the maintainers of com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.util.Fields    
WARNING: Use --illegal-access=warn to enable warnings of further illegal reflective access operations 
WARNING: All illegal access operations will be denied in a future release Security framework of XStream not initialized, XStream is probably vulnerable. 
Error in NonGUIDriver java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Problem loading XML from:'/jmeter-master/apache-jmeter-3.3/bin/Artemis_AWS.jmx', conversion error com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.ConversionException: 
---- Debugging information ---- 
cause-exception : com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.ConversionException 
cause-message : 
first-jmeter-class  : org.apache.jmeter.save.converters.HashTreeConverter.unmarshal(HashTreeConverter.java:67)    
class               : org.apache.jmeter.save.ScriptWrapper    
required-type       : org.apache.jmeter.save.ScriptWrapper    
converter-type      : org.apache.jmeter.save.ScriptWrapperConverter    
path                :   jmeterTestPlan/hashTree/hashTree/hashTree[2]/PublisherSampler 
line number         : 140 
version             : 2.13.20170723    -------------------------------
```

This is what is in line 140 of the jmx file:

```
<RandomVariableConfig guiclass="TestBeanGUI" testclass="RandomVariableConfig" 
  testname="tableNumber-100" enabled="true">
  <stringProp name="variableName">tableNumber</stringProp>
  <stringProp name="outputFormat">000</stringProp>
  <stringProp name="minimumValue">100</stringProp>
  <stringProp name="maximumValue">200</stringProp>
  <stringProp name="randomSeed">100</stringProp>
  <boolProp name="perThread">false</boolProp>
</RandomVariableConfig>                             <------ line 140
<hashTree/>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the log file you're running JMeter 2.13, not JMeter 3.3:

> version             : 2.13.20170723    -------------------------------
> ^^^^

And [Random Variable](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Random_Variable) element is available **since JMeter 2.3.3** so you need to upgrade your JMeter to at least 2.3.3 or higher in order to be able to use this config element.

[Ubuntu has JMeter 2.13](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=jmeter) in its repositories which is kind of old so you need to download whatever version you need from [JMeter Downloads](https://jmeter.apache.org/download_jmeter.cgi) page and install it manually

More information: [How to Get Started With JMeter: Installation & Test Plans](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-get-started-jmeter-installation-test-plans)

In general according to [JMeter Best Practrices](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#use_latest_version) you should always be using the latest version of JMeter so consider upgrading to [JMeter 5.3](http://www.jmeter-archive.org/ANNOUNCE-Apache-JMeter-5-3-released-td5728863.html) instead of 3.3 which is kind of old as well.

Comment: Thank you for youR hint, I will try this and report afterwards. The reason for version 3.3 was, that the git project needs this to work.

Comment: Now I am getting the "Error: Java version is too low to run JMeter. Needs at least Java >= 1.8.0." But when I typ java -version, I get: openjdk version "11.0.9" 2020-10-20
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.9+11-Ubuntu-0ubuntu1.18.04.1)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 11.0.9+11-Ubuntu-0ubuntu1.18.04.1, mixed mode, sharing). Should it not be enough?

Comment: It might be a JMeter bug, run it as `java -jar ApacheJMeter.jar`, it will bypass shell scripts checking for Java version, at the time of JMeter 3.3 Java 11 wasn't available. More information: [How Do I Run JMeter in Non-GUI Mode?](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/dear-abby-blazemeter-how-do-i-run-jmeter-non-gui-mode)